# Bootstrap input sizing and position problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some problems with sizing and positioning bootstrap input filds.

I've added the css class="form-controle" to the inputs.

and Now it looks like this:

[image]

But this is a cloze text to fill in and it should look like this:

[image]

It should always be like this: <> input <> input

Any hint how I can get this view with bootstrap?

Comment: add class form-inline for form tag

Comment: You can surround elements with div's with class "col-*-*" Or with 'form-inline'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this example in bootstrap site

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 0):

Try form-inline - check it on bootstrap's site [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```